# Does NuGet packages have versions in Azure DevOps Nuget Tool Installer task?

Tags: .net, azure, json.net, nuget, azure-devops

This is a visual studio 2015, dotnet framework 4.6.1 application. I have tried to build and deploy from Azure DevOps onto Azure cloud. The error on deployment is "NewtonSoft.json.dll missing".

[image: Error]

So when i replace the Azure DevOps artifacts with the visual studio build dll's and files the application works. This is UAT test i'm performing where in the build pipeline i have used NuGet Packages task. The final artifacts generated contains newtonsoft file but i crosschecked it is not same size as the one generated on visual studio build.

[image: DevOps-build]
[image: VS-build]

The tasks i set with versions:

[image: NuGet task]

[image: Nuget2]

Do i have to provide different version of Nuget task to reference the correct newtonsoft.json file since i do have this file in my artifacts. Does providing a wrong version cause this missing file error. Please assist.

Comment: The version of NuGet you're using is completely irrelevant to the version of the package you're downloading. Look at your application's `packages.config`.

Comment: log4net version="2.0.8" Microsoft.AspNet.Razor version="3.2.6"
  Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages version="3.2.6"
  Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure version="1.0.0.0" . These are the versions of the packages. Where does newtonsoft.json.dll fit in.