# How to clear vsts cache, Nuget cache to avoid compatibility issue in dll's

Tags: .net, dll, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

How do I clear the NuGet and VSTS cache from my local Azure DevOps environment so that when I use use NuGet agent it does not use the previous build dlls, but uses a new one instead.

I'm trying to resolve the error shown below:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

[image: error]

Comment: Clearing the package folder won't help with the error message you're seeing. Something in your project was built against Newtonsoft.Json version 10.0.0.0, but your app has a different version of that dll in the bin\ folder. Normally NuGet automatically adds a binding redirect so that the .NET CLR will accept loading the different version, but that's not working for you for some reason. It's very difficult to know why without a [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ziv check this previous detailed unanswered question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362281/does-nuget-packages-have-versions-in-azure-devops-nuget-tool-installer-task?noredirect=1#comment93602880_53362281

Comment: If I create a new ASP.NET project in Visual Studio, then set up a Azure Devops pipeline with this new project, it works fine. Unless you can provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'm afraid I just can't help. I know it's difficult to provide us the right information when you don't know what the cause of the error is, but so far your questions have only asked about things that can't help, and you haven't provided us with enough information so that we can help.

Comment: Something that may be useful is if you can tell us if your nuget references are with packages.config or PackageReference? I'm not sure ASP.NET supports PackageReference. You should see binding redirects in your web.config, and if you use the NuGet package manager UI to change versions of Newtonsoft.Json, the version specified in the binding redirect should change as well. If this does not happen, I recommend focusing your research on that.